# Dart : Why should overriding method's parameter be "wider" than parent's one? (probably topic about Contravariant) Part2

Tags: oop, inheritance

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class

> Argument types must be the same type as (or a supertype of) the
> overridden method’s argument types. In the preceding example, the
> contrast setter of SmartTelevision changes the argument type from int
> to a supertype, num.

---

I was looking at the above explanation and wondering why the arguments of subtype member methods need to be defined more "widely"(generally) than the original class's one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types

```
class AnimalShelter {

    Animal getAnimalForAdoption() {
        // ...
    }
    
    void putAnimal(Animal animal) {
        //...
    }
}



class CatShelter extends AnimalShelter {
//↓ Definitions that are desirable in the commentary
    void putAnimal(Object animal) {
        // ...
    }


//↓Definitions that are not desirable in the commentary
    void putAnimal(Cat animal) {
        // ...
    }
//I can't understand why this definition is risky.
//What specific problems can occur?
}
```

I think this wikipedia sample code is very easy to understand, so what kind of specific problem (fault) can occur if the argument of the member method of the subtype is defined as a more "narrower"(specific) type?

Even if it is explained in natural language, it will be abstract after all, so it would be very helpful if you could give me a complete working code and an explanation using it.

Comment: If `shelter` is an object of type `AnimalShelter`, then it must be legal to call `shelter.putAnimal(animal)` with any kind of animal. Your CatShelter breaks this rule, since CatShelter's putAnimal takes only cats.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry that I can't understand your explanation.
Could you give me a complete working code and an explanation using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider an example where you have a class hierarchy:

```
      Animal
     /     \
  Mammal   Reptile
  /   \
Dog   Cat
```

with superclasses (wider types) above subclasses (narrower types).

Now suppose you have classes:

```dart
class Base {
  void takeObject(Mammal mammal) {
    // ...
  }

  Mammal returnObject() {
    // ...
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  // ...
}
```

The public members of a class specify an interface: a contract to the callers.  In this case, the `Base` class advertises a `takeObject` method that accepts any `Mammal` argument. *Every* instance of a `Base` class thus is expected to conform to this interface.

Following the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), because `Derived` extends `Base`, a `Derived` instance *is* a `Base`, and therefore it too must conform to that same `Base` class interface: its `takeObject` method also must accept any `Mammal` argument.

If `Derived` overrode `takeObject` to accept only `Dog` arguments:

```dart
class Derived extends Base {
  @override
  void takeObject(Dog mammal) { // ERROR
    // ...
  }
}
```

that would violate the contract from the `Base` class's interface. `Derived`'s override of `takeObject` could be invoked with a `Cat` argument, which should be allowed according to the interface declared by `Base`.  Since this is unsafe, Dart's static type system normally prevents you from doing that. (An exception is if you add the `covariant` keyword to disable type-safety and indicate that you personally guarantee that `Derived.takeObject` will never be called with any `Mammal`s that aren't `Dog`s.  If that claim is wrong, you will end up with a runtime error.)

Note that it'd be okay if `Derived` overrode `takeObject` to accept an `Animal` argument instead:

```dart
class Derived extends Base {
  @override
  void takeObject(Animal mammal) { // OK
    // ...
  }
}
```

because that would still conform to the contract of `Base.takeObject`: it's safe to call `Derived.takeObject` with any `Mammal` since all `Mammal`s are also `Animal`s.

Note that the behavior for return values is the opposite: it's okay for an overridden method to return a narrower type, but returning a wider type would violate the contract of the `Base` interface.  For example:

```dart
class Derived extends Base {
  @override
  Dog returnObject() { // OK, a `Dog` is a `Mammal`, as required by `Base`
    // ...
  }
}
```

but:

```dart
class Derived extends Base {
  @override
  Animal returnObject() { // ERROR: Could return a `Reptile`, which is not a `Mammal`
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed explanation.

I think the starting point of the logical development of your explanation is that "the descendant class must follow the contractor of the parent class (the class from which it inherits)".

I think this is usually correct, but is this stated in the Dart or Flutter documentation as a definition?

If not, then I guess it is just a prerequisite knowledge of programming languages in general that a beginning student should have at the time they start learning Dart.

Comment: But where does someone whose first language is Dart get that prerequisite knowledge?

Is that place Stackoverflow?

Comment: @森口万太郎 It's a general principle of object oriented programming.  It's the logical conclusion from having polymorphism; how else could it work if you have an object of type `Derived` but have a reference to it with a static type of `Base`?

Comment: No, my comment is not about this specific question. I personally believe that it is necessary to check the source of evidence and information on any issue in general, especially on the "general principle".

If a person who does not have sufficient knowledge of the premises does not do so, he/she will not have a concrete starting point for logic.I would like to confirm about "polymorphism".

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(){

  Animal a1 = Animal();
  Cat c1 = Cat();
  Dog d1 = Dog();

  AnimalCage ac1 = AnimalCage();
  CatCage cc1 = CatCage();

  AnimalCage ac2 = CatCage();

  ac2.setAnimal(d1);

  //cc1.setAnimal(d1);

}

class AnimalCage{
  Animal? _animal;

  void setAnimal(Animal animal){
    print('animals setter');
    _animal = animal;
  }
}

class CatCage extends AnimalCage{
  Cat? _cat;

  @override
  void setAnimal(covariant Cat animal){
    print('cats setter');

    _cat = animal;
    /*
    if(animal is Cat){
      _cat = animal;
    }else{
      print('$animal is not Cat!');
    }
     */
  }
}

class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{}
```

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'Dog' is not a subtype of type 'Cat' of 'animal'
```

In the above code, even if the setAnimal method receives a Dog instance, a compile error does not occur and a runtime error occurs, so making the parameter the same type as the superclass's one and checking the type inside the method is necessary.