# Why can't the parameter type of a @override method be “tighten” in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

## Background

I am new to Dart and recently I've been reading some docs about Dart sound type system until I ran into a section called [Use sound parameter types when overriding methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#use-sound-parameter-types-when-overriding-methods)

It states that

> The parameter of an overridden method must have either the same type
> or a supertype of the corresponding parameter in the superclass. Don’t
> “tighten” the parameter type by replacing the type with a subtype of
> the original parameter.

and shows me a block of code saying
[image]

## What I am confused of

My question is that, of course, by prohibiting parameter type "tighten" in an override method we can prevent

> define a cat and send it after an alligator

```
class Animal {
  chase(Animal a) {}
}

class Mouse extends Animal {}

class Alligator extends Animal {}

class CatA extends Animal {
  @override
// error on this line
  void chase(Mouse x) {} // It makes sense. Cat chases Mouse
}

class CatB extends Animal {
  @override
  // error on this line
  void chase(Alligator x) {} // Cat chases Alligator ? You can't be serious!
}
```

But how about using a `Object`(witch is the supertype of almost all others) as its parameter type

```
class Cat extends Animal {
  @override
  void chase(Object x) { // Now this Cat can chase anything.....

  }
}

void main() {
  var cat = Cat();
  cat.chase(Alligator()); // Again, we are trying to let a little pussy chase a terrifying beast!
}
// This piece of code works
```

What is it all about, this does not makes sense to me at all...Furthermore, what if I create a supercat that extends a `Cat`, which can indeed chase after a `Alligator`

```
class SuperCat extends Cat {
  @override
  // error on this line
  void chase(Alligator x) { // I make a SuperCat chasing after a Alligator intentionally, but it doesn't work...

  }
}
```

These things above are really blowing my minds off, do I get it wrong in some way or is there anything more under the hood that makes it this way?

## Update

Thanks to @jamesdlin and @Abion47, I could finally figure out most of the puzzles, but there is still one more problem to solve. As @jamesdlin mentioned, `contract of the base class method` must be honored when overriding a method. Taking `Animal` and `Cat` for example, `Animal.chase` makes a contract saying **`chase` must be compatible to accept any `Animal`, no matter it is `Alligator` or
`Mouse`**, but does this contract also make a restrction that **`chase` must not be able to accept any other `Object` excepts for `Animal`**？*(It is natural to think about it because you can't pass a casual `Object` parameter into `Animal.chase`)* And if it does, why does Dart allow widening `Cat.chase` parameter type from `Animal` to `Object`? Doesn't it violate the contract made by `Animal.chase`?

Comment: And one more things I am really curious about, as far as I am concerned the `override` in Dart resembles more `overwrite` in Java, since `overwrite` means more to me that "rewrite the inner logic of this method while remaining what it previously looks like from the view of outside" and `override` means enabling polymorphism to a method or a class more accurately. does not this two words differentiate between each other in Dart?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72683721/

Comment: I haven't used Java in many, many years, but AFAIK it does not have an `overwrite` keyword or annotation.  Over*riding* methods in Dart is the same as in Java: to enable polymorphism while still honoring the contract of the base class method.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thx! You're right, that's my fault here, there are only `override` and `overload` keywords in Java, seems like I mess up with `override`, `overload` and `overwrite`

Comment: "but does this contract also make a restriction that `chase` must not be able to accept any other `Object` except for `Animal`...?" No, it doesn't.  Or rather, it is not implied nor logically required by Dart's static type system.  Forget about method overrides; consider a case where you simply want to make a change to a function.  Widening the argument type would not break any existing callers, but narrowing it could...

Comment: ... Widening the argument type of `chase` can't break callers that expect an `Animal`-but-nothing-wider because there's no way for callers to specify such an expectation, so such callers can't exist in the first place.  There perhaps are other programming languages that allow specifying more precise function contracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer referenced by jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596495/dart-why-should-overriding-methods-parameter-be-wider-than-parents-one-p/72683721#72683721) has the details of why this isn't allowed, but I'll try to give a nutshell version.

```dart
abstract class Animal {
  void chase(Animal a) { ... }
}

class Mouse extends Animal {}

class Alligator extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {
  @override
  void chase(Mouse x) { ... } // No-no
}
```

In theory, this would be fine, since `Mouse` extends `Animal` and `Cat` is just restricting what kind of animal can be passed to `chase`.

But think about what happens with polymorphism. The hard rule is that any classes that extend and override a base class must be compatible with that base class. That ensures that, even if the function is called on a handle that is typed to the base class, it is guaranteed that the call will go to the correct function definition in the overriding class.

This is what makes abstract classes possible - if there was an implementation of a function in a derived class that wasn't compatible with the same function in the base class, it would be impossible to treat instances of inherited classes as though they were instances of the base class.

For example, take the example from the article but instead of explicitly creating a `Cat`, have it be some randomly generated animal:

```dart
Animal a = RandomAnimalFactory.create();
a.chase(Alligator());
```

What is the exact type of `a`? You have no way of knowing. All you know is that it is some subtype of `Animal`.

Now look at the call to `a.chase(Alligator())`. Would that succeed? Well, yes, because `Animal.chase` requires an `Animal` and `Alligator` is an `Animal`. No problems there.

But imagine if a subclass could restrict the type of that parameter, e.g. if `Cat` could restrict it to `Mouse`. Now it's unclear whether that call would succeed because even though you know that `a` is an `Animal`, you don't know what *kind* of `Animal`. What if it's a type that makes `Alligator` no longer a valid parameter? In order to know, the type system would have to unpack the declared type of the variable to examine the actual type, and only then would it know whether the call would succeed. This flies in the face of inheritance, where a type that extends a base type can be interchangeable with any of its sibling types.

All of a sudden, what used to be a simple matter has become extremely complex. Not only does it make the implementation of an OOP-based type system astronomically more complicated, it completely undermines the point of inheritance.

Comment: The `RandomAnimalFactory` example is awesome, thank you for the detailed answer! I can finally understand why allowing parameter type tightening in an override method is risky. And there is only one thing that I am still struggling with, `Animal.chase` declare some "restrictions" for those who want to override it. For the one thing, `chase` must be compatible to accept any `Animal`, no matter it is `Alligator` or a `Mouse`. For another, `chase` must only be able to accept `Animal`. But consider a `Cat` override `chase` with a `Object` parameter type, does it break the second constraints?

Comment: @HonmaMeiko Overriding `Cat.chase` to accept an `Object` instead of an `Animal` wouldn't be a problem since it would still be compatible with anything that could be passed to `Animal.chase`, thus inheritance is preserved.